# unhashable type: 'Series'

Tags: python, dataframe, plot

I'm trying to plot a 8 columns dataframe using Jupyter, it works fine with 4 columns however it shows an error `unhashable type: 'Series'` when i try to plot more than 4. Here is my code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline
df = pd.read_csv("adherent.csv")
plt.scatter(df['X33L'], df['X44L'], df['X3L'], df['X117L'], df['X109L'], df['X61L'], df['X126L'], df['X106L'])
```

and here is the error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_16692/35224942.py in <module>
----> 1 plt.scatter(df['X33L'], df['X44L'], df['X3L'], df['X117L'], df['X109L'], df['X61L'], df['X126L'], df['X106L'])

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in scatter(x, y, s, c, marker, cmap, norm, vmin, vmax, alpha, linewidths, edgecolors, plotnonfinite, data, **kwargs)
   3066         vmin=None, vmax=None, alpha=None, linewidths=None, *,
   3067         edgecolors=None, plotnonfinite=False, data=None, **kwargs):
-> 3068     __ret = gca().scatter(
   3069         x, y, s=s, c=c, marker=marker, cmap=cmap, norm=norm,
   3070         vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, alpha=alpha, linewidths=linewidths,

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1359     def inner(ax, *args, data=None, **kwargs):
   1360         if data is None:
-> 1361             return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
   1362 
   1363         bound = new_sig.bind(ax, *args, **kwargs)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in scatter(self, x, y, s, c, marker, cmap, norm, vmin, vmax, alpha, linewidths, edgecolors, plotnonfinite, **kwargs)
   4541             marker_obj = marker
   4542         else:
-> 4543             marker_obj = mmarkers.MarkerStyle(marker)
   4544 
   4545         path = marker_obj.get_path().transformed(

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\markers.py in __init__(self, marker, fillstyle)
    234         self._marker_function = None
    235         self._set_fillstyle(fillstyle)
--> 236         self._set_marker(marker)
    237 
    238     def _recache(self):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\markers.py in _set_marker(self, marker)
    318             self._marker_function = self._set_tuple_marker
    319         elif (not isinstance(marker, (np.ndarray, list)) and
--> 320               marker in self.markers):
    321             self._marker_function = getattr(
    322                 self, '_set_' + self.markers[marker])

TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'
```

Comment: it may use other columns as parameters, not data to plot - `scatter` should get only one column for `X`, one column for `Y` and rest as parameters. It has definition `scatter(x, y, s, color, marker, cmap, norm, ...)` and `cmap, norm, ...` may need somthing different then `Series`/`column`. You should read documentation for `scatter`

Comment: See doc for [scatter](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html)

Answer (score 0):

I recently dealt with this issue, which may have a straightforward answer. If we look at your line:

```
plt.scatter(df['X33L'], df['X44L'], df['X3L'], df['X117L'], df['X109L'], df['X61L'], df['X126L'], df['X106L'])
```

You should inspect the values that are coming out of each column. For example, some of them may be strings, or integers, and in other cases they may be objects.

For example, if you look at:

```
df['X61L']
```

You may see that it has a value, name, and datatype. In my case, I had a column which was a GUID being stored as an an object datatype. example, inspecting the results for a single row in this df gave me:

> 0    4f453118-6e97-49c1-a8c3-b74808e1018d
> Name: GUID, dtype: object

The solution for this was pretty simple, when I created df, to extract the underlying value, eg:

```
df['X61L'][0]
```

Other solutions are to update the column and cast it to an integer/string. Eg:

```
df['GUID'] = df['GUID'].astype(str)
```

Hope this helps!